# Excel FIND function is not acting as expected, giving false negatives

Tags: excel

I have two Excel sheets, and each one has a column with e-mail addresses in them. I am trying to write a formula that checks one sheet to see if that e-mail address is already located there. If so, it returns "Yes". If not, it returns "No". This is the formula I am using.

`=IF(ISERROR(FIND(F2,'Group Contacts 2014'!F:F)),"No",IF(F2<>"","Yes","No"))`

**F2** is the e-mail address I am checking, and *'Group Contacts 2014'!F:F* is the column of e-mail addresses I am checking it against in the other sheet.

This formula is currently returning false negatives. For example, I have an e-mail address in both sheets but it is returning "No" for it. Any ideas on what is going awry?

Comment: Are there leading or trailing spaces in your false positive?

Comment: I agree with what @Roberto posted. Looks like a *MATCH* function to me. If you want to stick with your logic, you need to enter your formula differently as *array formula* which is not really advisable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/find-findb-functions-HP010342526.aspx) `FIND` locates a substring within a larger string. So it's not really a good choice when you want to search multiple cells.

```
FIND(find_text, within_text, [start_num])
```

I think you are looking for [`MATCH`,](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/match-function-HP010342679.aspx?CTT=1) which looks to see if a specified value appears in a particular range. Note that you probably want to specify `match_type = 0` in order to force the function to only accept exact matches.

```
MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])
```

Comment: That fixed it. I changed the formula to =IF(F2="","",IF(ISERROR(MATCH(F2,'Group Contacts 2014'!F:F,0)),"No","Yes")) and it is working now. Thanks Roberto.